# How the recurrence relation $a_{k}=a_{k-1}+k-1$ yields $a_{k}-a_1=k(k-1)/2$, $a_{1}=1$

Tags: real-analysis

I am unable to trace out how can in solve this recurrence relation,

Comment: Perhaps induction?

Comment: You may want to elaborate a little bit more in your question. What have you tried so far? Generally, one sentence questions are frowned upon on SE.

Comment: ok, let me include the major part from which i sorted out this problem

Comment: How does your title relate to the question, they don't seem related.

Comment: They are related if you start solving the problem in the title, you will start with the recurrence relation mentioned in further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that if we have $a_k=a_{k-1}+k-1$, $a_1=1$, then 
$$a_2=1+1$$
$$a_3=2+1+1$$
$$a_4=3+2+1+1$$
We can clearly state that $a_k$ is equal to one more than the sum of the first $k-1$ natural numbers. It just so happens that the formula for the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, which can be proven easily using induction. Once you know this, you can say that
$$a_k=\frac{(k-1)(k-1+1)}{2}+1$$
$$a_k-1=\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$$
$$a_k-a_1=\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$$
Which is the answer that you were supposed to get.

Answer (score 1):

Just $$\sum_{i=2}^k(a_i-a_{i-1})=a_k-a_1=\sum_{i=2}^k(i-1)=\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$$

Comment: good evening Michael, have you got some new inequalites?

Comment: Good evening Sonnhard. Yes of course! But I am saving it for our team.

Comment: i wish your Team all the best. May i ask you, if you have a phone number, Michael?

Comment: it would be nice if we can talk together, if it is possible

Comment: This little conversation has made me so curious

Comment: Me too, what happened then?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: prove by induction that $$a_k=\frac{1}{2}\left(2-k+k^2\right)$$ then $$a_k-1=1+\frac{k^2-k}{2}-1$$
Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

We have that $a_{k}=a_{k-1}+k-1 \Leftrightarrow a_k-a_{k-1} = k-1$

We know that $\sum_{i=2}^{k} (a_i-a_{i-1}) = a_{k}-a_{1} = a_{k}-1$ since $a_1 = 1$

But also, note that $\sum_{i=2}^{k} a_i-a_{i-1} = \sum_{i=2}^{k}(i-1) = 1+2+...k-1 = \frac{k(k-1)}{2} $